# Resizing a bitmap in xml

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

For my splash screen I use a style with has a drawable defined as xml.
There I'm using a bitmap to include the picture.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <color android:color="@color/white"/>
  </item>
  <item
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/splash_logo"
        android:gravity="center"/>
  </item>

</layer-list>
```

The picture has a size of 1024x390 and I have no option to scale it down.
How can I center and scale it in the xml to be in center and fit into the screen?

I've tried a lot of things, like setting width and height of parent item and bitmap should fill the parent or setting padding but all my approaches weren't good. I also have read some other stackoverflow answers to this topic but none of the solutions worked for me.

Are there any other solutions I can try to scale the image to that it fits the screen and is centered?

Comment: have you tried programatically set layout parameters to it? or tried android Picasso to fit it in?

Comment: Show your xml where you set in an actual view?

Comment: Create a drawable for each of `drawable-XXXX` sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach requires a higher API level (23 maybe?) but it'll do exactly what you want.

```
<item
    android:height="200dp"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:drawable="@drawable/splash_logo"
    android:gravity="center">
</item>
```

Edit the width/height to be whatever you need.

Comment: How does this resize the item? The splash screen drawable is rendered from the XML, as far as I am aware you can't dynamically change these variables based on screen width before the view is visible to the user.

Comment: You can in api 23 and higher.